# IntelliJ - keymap to navigate to function

Tags: intellij-idea

When I use IntelliJ, and a certain line in the code calls a function, if I put the cursor on the function call, hold the ctrl key and pound the left button in the mouse, IntelliJ brings me to the function that I call.

My question is do I have any option to get the same functionality without touching the mouse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This navigation shortcut is called `Go to declaration`.

It can be used by either pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Mouse Click</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>

Additionally, there is also a `Go to implementation` shortcut:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Mouse Click</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>

Comment: What is the difference between "Go to declaration" and "Go to implementation" ?

Comment: For example, if there is an interface method `MyInterface.foo()` and the implementation `MyImpl.foo()`, going to "declaration" will navigate to the interface and going to "implementation" the implementation. If there is no interface, both shortcuts often behave equally.